# swift 4: modify notification content before sending it

Tags: iphone, swift, notifications, background, fetch

My App sends a daily randomly selected question&Answer (Q&A) to the user where it gets the Data from the FMDB database. 
I have set a scheduled local notification to 8 AM every morning in the Main ViewController. So whenever the user opens the App the App will update the notification content to newly randomly selected Q&A. 
However, in case the user doesn't open the App for a day or so, the user will be getting the same Q&A every day instead of getting a new Q&A for every day.

I have tried to use background fetch so I check the time if it is 8 AM then update the content of the message. but unfortunately, it isn't reliable since in case the App was killed it will not perform the background check. Also, the App might not check the fetch at that specific time. 
I Also tried to use Extension Content Handler, However, since I'm new to Swift coding I couldn't manage to get it right. Moreover, I read an article says that Extension service Handlers are only used for remote push notifications.

I would like to hear from you ... How can I achieve what I'm aiming for using local scheduled notifications where I can modify the content before firing the notification.

Many Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: No at all, I'm just asking if somebody guides me to the concepts and methods to be used to achieve such. or lets say the best approach to do so.